# vectorized exponent for pow in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Rcpp allows to vectorize some operations, which is great. But for `pow` only the base number can be a vector, not the exponent. Typically, on compilation:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector puissancedCpp(NumericVector base, double exp){
    return pow(base,exp);
}
```

works but not:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector puissancedCpp(NumericVector base, NumericVector exp){
    return pow(base,exp);
}
```

What would be the recommended way to perform what in R would be:

```
c(0,1,2,3)^c(4,3,2,1)
```

in the middle of other things done in C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option, assuming your compiler supports C++11:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> vpow(const std::vector<double>& base, const std::vector<double>& exp) {
    std::vector<double> res(base.size());
    std::transform(base.begin(), base.end(), exp.begin(), res.begin(),
                  [&](double lhs, double rhs) -> double {
                    return std::pow(lhs, rhs);
                  });
    return res;
}


/*** R

c(0,1,2,3)^c(4,3,2,1) 
#[1] 0 1 4 3
vpow(0:3, c(4,3,2,1))
#[1] 0 1 4 3

*/
```

---

If you're working with an older compiler, you could achieve this using

```
double dpow(const double lhs, const double rhs) {
  return std::pow(lhs, rhs);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> vpow98(const std::vector<double>& base, const std::vector<double>& exp) {
    std::vector<double> res(base.size());
    std::transform(base.begin(), base.end(), exp.begin(), res.begin(), dpow);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Very nice.  The whole point of Rcpp is to make exactly this easy.

Comment: Sure thing.  We had C++11 supported via plugins for a while -- maybe 13.04 or eve 12.10.    The current g++ 4.9.* is good.

Answer (score 12):

An alternative if you for some reason can't use C++11

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;  

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector vecpow(const NumericVector base, const NumericVector exp) {
  NumericVector out(base.size());
  std::transform(base.begin(), base.end(),
                 exp.begin(), out.begin(), ::pow);
  return out;
}

/*** R
vecpow(c(0:3), c(4:1))
***/
```

which produces

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("vecpow.cpp")

R> vecpow(c(0:3), c(4:1))
[1] 0 1 4 3
R>
```

Comment: Super nice. This is actually for some reason unknown to me even 10% faster than nrussel's answer

Comment: Faster because it uses native Rcpp types and hence avoids a copy of the underlying data to and from STL containers.

Comment: Trying this last code in Rstudio in 2021. I get the following error when I source it `error: no matching function for call to 'transform'`

Comment: The solution (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991570/compatibility-of-rcpp-code-involving-stdtransform-in-package) is to replace ::pow with static_cast<double(*)(double, double)>(::pow)