# Compatibility of Rcpp code involving std::transform in package

Tags: r, std, rcpp

I am in the process of finishing a package I've been working on. All checks look good and it compiles without problems on my computer. `win-builder` has no problems with the package as well. As further check, I've tried to install from source on the computer of a colleague and it fails. The problem comes from a Rcpp function that I've taken from [a StackOverflow thread on vector powers in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106492/vectorized-exponent-for-pow-in-rcpp):

```
NumericVector vecpow(const NumericVector base, const NumericVector exp) {

  NumericVector out(base.size());

  std::transform(base.begin(), base.end(),
                 exp.begin(), out.begin(), ::pow);
  return out;
}
```

This compiles and works fine for me, but throws an error for my colleague when installing, involving

```
error: no matching function function for call to 'transform'
```

and

```
candidate function template not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 5 were provided.
```

I can reproduce the error for instance by replacing `::pow` in the original code by `pow`. I'm on Windows 8.1, my colleague is on Mac. The colleague maintains his own packages involving extensive amounts of Rcpp code and usually has no problems with compiling.

I assume that this might be a compiler problem. The original thread has some alternative code involving C++11 (thread is already five years old), so in principle, I could replace the problematic code using alternatives. However, as I'm not very experienced with this, this would be trial and error. My question is: Is there a simple reason why this error pops up? And how can I modify my code in order to be sure that the package will be installable and usable for most users?

Comment: We used example with `std::transform()` for a decade or longer in presentations about Rcpp so you likely are doing something wrong but I don't have time to dig now. But not that there _ten_ different examples of using it in the [Rcpp unit test directory with C++ code used by tests](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/tinytest/cpp).

Comment: the error is rising from `c++` calling the unary transform variant instead of the binary one.

Comment: @Abdessabour is spot one, I also just glanced at the (as always a little dense) [documentation here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).   You can also just shrug and move on and use a loop over your two vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, will happily do the reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error is caused because the compiler can't match the `std::pow` function as binary operation (this may be due to the fact that it has at least two overloads and the compiler can't guess the types float/double) giving rise to the following note :

> note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_BinaryOperation'

And then it falls back to the unary `std::transform` which only has 4 arguments pushing the second note:

> note: candidate function template not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 5 were provided

Compilation stops as it hasn't found a valid `std::transform` to apply to the specified arguments.
Switching from `pow` to `powf` stops this issue as the compiler doesn't have to resolve any overloads, however precision might be lost due to this change :

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector vecpow(const NumericVector base, const NumericVector exp) {
  NumericVector out(base.size());
  std::transform(base.begin(), base.end(),
                 exp.begin(), out.begin(), ::powf);
    
  return out;
}
") -> pow
pow(1:5,5:1)
[1]  1 16 27 16  5
```

Another work around would be to use static cast i.e replace `::pow` with `static_cast<double(*)(double, double)>(::pow)` to tell the compiler to use the `double` overload of `pow`