# R Rcpp std::transform fail

Tags: r, rcpp

This code worked in [2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106492/vectorized-exponent-for-pow-in-rcpp) but doesn't now. It reports that there is no matching function for call to transform. Is there some issue with finding the std code now?

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;  

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector vecpow(const NumericVector base, const NumericVector exp) {
  NumericVector out(base.size());
  std::transform(base.begin(), base.end(),
                 exp.begin(), out.begin(), ::pow);
  return out;
}

/*** R
vecpow(c(0:3), c(4:1))
***/
```

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991570/compatibility-of-rcpp-code-involving-stdtransform-in-package) that involves replacing `::pow` with `static_cast<double(*)(double, double)>(::pow)` At least, it works with the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the world around us does change every now and then.

If you consult a [C++ reference you see that std::transformed has changed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). I am not enough of a language lawyer to see what it dislikes about `std::pow` now (though I *can* tell you that you called the wrong (C-level) `::pow`) but here are two that work *by using a lambda function* as in the other older answer.

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> vecpow(const std::vector<double> base,
                           const std::vector<double> exp) {

    std::vector<double> out(base.size());
    std::transform(base.begin(), base.end(), exp.begin(), out.begin(),
                   [&](double lhs, double rhs) -> double { 
                                        return std::pow(lhs, rhs); });
    return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector vecpow2(Rcpp::NumericVector base, Rcpp::NumericVector exp) {

    Rcpp::NumericVector out(base.size());
    std::transform(base.begin(), base.end(), exp.begin(), out.begin(),
                   [&](double lhs, double rhs) -> double {
                                        return std::pow(lhs, rhs); });
    return out;
}

/*** R
vecpow(0:3, 4:1)
vecpow2(0:3, 4:1)
*/
```

#### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("answer.cpp")

> vecpow(0:3, 4:1)
[1] 0 1 4 3

> vecpow2(0:3, 4:1)
[1] 0 1 4 3
>
```

Comment: @jerryn Zero feedback?  That is ... unusual for you :)