# R Rcpp how to use a vector in pow

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to convert R code with a power element (x^y) to Rcpp. Rcpp uses pow(x,y) but it appears to not be vectorized. The following example returns NaN NaN.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector vecTest(NumericVector x) {
  
  return pow(x, 0.25);
}

/*** R
test <- c(-1.19556e+12, -1.24111e+12)
vecTest(test)
*/
```

I can write a for loop that would step through the elements of the x vector but I'm wondering if there is something I'm just missing.

Comment: Hmm. This question makes it look like the base is vectorized: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106492/vectorized-exponent-for-pow-in-rcpp

Comment: `c(-1.19556e+12, -1.24111e+12)^ .25` return `NaN NaN` in R as well (so it's not just an Rcpp thing). What values were you expecting?

Comment: You are aware that you are trying to leave real numbers with your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sometimes helps to

- look at the header file defining the function you want to use
- look at some unit tests deploying the function you want to use
- keep your examples simple
- vary the arguments a little
- be sure you hit the function from the namespace you want to hit

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector mypow(Rcpp::NumericVector x, double expo) {
    return Rcpp::pow(x, expo);
}

/*** R
v <- c(2, 3, 4, 1.2e12, -1.2e12)
mypow(v, 2)
mypow(v, 0.5)
*/
```

#### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/68852817/answer.cpp")

> v <- c(2,3,4)

> mypow(v, 2)
[1] 4.00e+00 9.00e+00 1.60e+01 1.44e+24 1.44e+24

> mypow(v, 0.5)
[1] 1.41421e+00 1.73205e+00 2.00000e+00 1.09545e+06         NaN
>
```

Seems to work as advertised. Vector argument for exponentiation by a scalar.

*Edit:* Updated to show some 'large' values in your example. Roots of negative reals don't work, but that is a *math* issue and not a question of the compiler, library or package.

Comment: I hope the example meets the simple criterion. I don't know where to find the header file; in fact I don't think I knew there was one. I'm pretty sure you don't mean Rcpp.h. I'm also not entirely clear about what a unit test is. I did do experiments with integer values for the exponent and also simple computations like 1./4. instead of .25. Your mypow function once I understood it gets a stiletto award (ie, much more precise than a hammer) for subtlety, elegance and ex-post obviousness to a newbie.

Comment: You may just want to brew a decent cup of coffee and start to explore the fact that you are dealing with _open_ source.  Each package you use here has source code. _Code is documentation_.  The `Rcpp.h` header calls (many !!) others, that is arguable tricky to read but _at least it is there_.  As for unit tests, that is my favourite source and by using `tinyest`, the one by Rcpp are installed along with the package.  Just look at the subdirectories of your installed package.